# CSS width transition not working at all

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

Hi I'm trying to animate the `width` of the `span` inside the `a` of this `nav`

```
<nav class="navigator">
   <ul>
    <li><a href="#home">H<span>home</span></a></li>
    <li><a title="What?" href="#what">W<span>what</span></a></li>
    <li><a title="Porfolio" href="#works">P<span>works</span></a></li>
    <li><a title="Who?" href="#who">W<span>who</span></a></li>
    <li><a title="Where?" href="#where">W<span>where</span></a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

here it is the `CSS`

```
header nav ul li a{
    position: relative;
    width: 40px;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #000;
}
header nav ul li a:hover span{
    width: auto;
    overflow: visible;
    text-align: right;
}
header nav ul li a span{
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    right: 45px;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition:width 0.25s;
    -webkit-transition:width .25s;
    -moz-transition: width 0.25s;
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

As you can see I'm trying to animate the `width`, but, instead of growing gradually the `span` is only showing up without any `transition`. 
To let you figure out the effect that I'm trying to  get check out the `nav` of this site 
:http://kitkat.com/

I made a fiddle of my own `nav`:http://jsfiddle.net/ZUhsn/  where the problem comes out.

Hope I gave you all the information to try to solve my issue.
Cheers.

Comment: if your width is not an issue change the span width from auto to a fixed size.

Comment: Yeah, I see that with fixed width it works, but how to make it work with `auto` width?

Comment: @steo, why do you need `auto` width? Would `100%` give you the effect you are after?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Try this:

```
header nav ul li a:hover{}
header nav ul li a:hover span{
    width: 100%; /* YOU'LL NEED TO ADJUST THIS, IT CANNOT BE AUTO*/
    overflow: visible;
    text-align: right;
}

header nav ul li a span{
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    right: 45px;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition:width 0.25s;
    -webkit-transition:width .25s;
    -moz-transition: width 0.25s;
    font-size: 16px;
    display:block; /*HERE IS MY OTHER CHANGE*/
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZUhsn/4/

Two issues:

Firstly, span is an inline element by default, so it doesn't have a width like you would expect. By applying `display:block;`, we turn it into a block-level element with width.

Secondly, you were transitioning to a width value of `'auto'`. Transitions can only animate across numerical values, so you'll have to give your ending transition a measurement with units.

Answer (score 5):

Just change `width : 100%` to your `span` on `hover` :

```
header nav ul li a:hover span{
    width : 100%;
    overflow: visible;
    text-align: right;
}
```

Check this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/niks999/CZhed/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick recreation of the information you provided:

```
    <style>
    .navigator
    {
        position: absolute;
        left: 200px;
        border:1px solid black;
    }

    .navigator span
    {
        position: absolute;
        -moz-transition: 0.5s;
        opacity: 0;
        right: 0px;
        z-index: -1;
    }

    .navigator a
    {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: black;
    }

    .navigator a:hover span
    {
        right: 100%;
        opacity: 1;
        -moz-transition: 0.5s;
    }
</style>

<nav class="navigator">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#home">
                H
                <span>
                    Home
                </span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a title="What?" href="#what">
                W
                <span>
                    What
                </span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a title="Portfolio" href="#works">
                P
                <span>
                    Works
                </span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a title="Who?" href="#who">
                W
                <span>
                    Who
                </span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a title="Where?" href="#where">
                W
                <span>
                    Where
                </span>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>


 </nav>
```

And its working quite perfectly...